# IONIC COM FIREBASE CLOUD FIRESTORE

Tags: angular, ionic, firebase, cloud, firestore

é uma pergunta simples, quero realizar esse select na collection com um where, como realizo?

this.usuarioCollection = this.db.collection('usuarios');
this.usuario = this.usuarioCollection.valueChanges();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.usuarioCollection = this.db.collection('usuarios', ref => {
        return ref.where('role', '==', '50');
      });

resolvido